# Initiate multiple class in class

Tags: python, class

I have multiple class in multiple files. for example,

File 1:

```
class gen_list ():
  def gen_list_spice(self):
    ...
```

File 2:

```
class gen_postsim ():
  def gen_postsim(self):
    ...
```

I am thinking to wrap it with another class which looks like this,

```
class char ()
   def __init__ (self, type):
     if (type == list):    
       ....... (load gen_list only<-- this part i do not know how to write)
     else 
       ....... (load both)
```

in the top wrapper, I would like to for example if I give `list` I will be able to use `gen_list_spice` and otherwise, I will be able to use both `gen_list_spice` and `gen_postsim` when I just need to call the object `char`

Comment: Classes are delcared as "class Name:" note: no parentheses. Also, I completely don't understand your last sentence.

Comment: basically i would like to only load certain class based on my input from the wrapper and not all.

Comment: Let me try to rephrase, based on my understanding of your question: based on the type of the argument in init, you want the class `char` to expose the methods from one class, **or** to expose the methods from two other classes? E.g. based on the init call, for it to inherit one class, or two classes?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "load gen_list" and "load both". What would loading them do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you do this, but you can import a file in any part of your file.

File 1 which should be named as `get_list.py`

```
class ListGenerator():

    def gen_list_spice(self):
        pass
```

File 2 which should be named as `gen_postsim.py`

```
class PostsimGenerator():

    def gen_postsim(self):
        pass
```

And in your wrapper File:

```
class char():

    def __init__(self, type):
        if type == list:
            from gen_list import ListGenerator
            gl = ListGenerator()
            gl.gen_list_spice()
        else:
            from gen_postsim import PostsimGenerator
            from gen_list import ListGenerator
            gp = PostsimGenerator()
            gp.gen_postsim()
```

But it's not a good practice to do this. You can use functions rather than classes and import them in the file header.

In file `gen_list.py`

```
def gen_list_spice():
    print("get list")
    pass
```

In file `gen_postsim.py`

```
def gen_postsim():
    print("gen postsim")
    pass
```

In your wrapper file

```
from gen_list import gen_list_spice
from gen_postsim import gen_postsim

class char():

    def __init__(self, type):
        if type == list:
            gen_list_spice()
        else:
            gen_list_spice()
            gen_postsim()
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and help, its work. thanks